# Understanding Multidimensional Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand the concept of multidimensional arrays in java. Below is the posted code.

```
    int [] [] [] x = new int [3] [] [];
    int i, j;
    x[0] = new int[4][];
    x[1] = new int[2][];
    x[2] = new int[5][]; 
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
     {
        for (j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) 
         {
            x[i][j] = new int [i + j + 1];
            System.out.println("size = " + x[i][j].length);
         }
     }
     }
```

I do not understand what is being stored in  "x[0] = new int[4][]; " and also what is the idea behind writing like that? Any suggestions would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multidimensional array is basically an array of arrays :) Like this:

```
int[][] X = new int[4][3];
```

means:

```
      X[0]   X[1]   X[2]   X[3]
X -> [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
     [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
     [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
```

And

```
int[][] X = new int[4][];
X[0] = new int[2]; 
X[1] = new int[1]; 
X[2] = new int[3]; 
X[3] = new int[2];
```

will produce an irregular array like this:

```
      X[0]   X[1]   X[2]   X[3]
X -> [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
     [    ]        [    ] [    ]
                   [    ]
```

So each of the X's "children" is another array. Simple as that, try not to overthink the concept, it is not as complex as it seems :)

Comment: "int [] [] [] x = new int [3] [] []" this is array initialization right?What does x[0] = new int[4][3]; means?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I missed one brackets pair, my bad, corrected :-)

Comment: In my example, the sizes of the children arrays are predefined (each holds 3 elements). If you do it with an empty bracket (new int[4][]) you can define a different size for each of the children.

Comment: can you please come up with a small diagram which sums up your explanation

Comment: Do you understand it now? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92605/discussion-between-mohan-babu-and-kelevandos).

Answer (score 2):

Java knows an array. The trick in java is, if you want a multidimensional array, you just create an array in an array.
With x[0] = new int[4][]; you are telling that there are 4 rows in the multidimensional array, but you don't fill them.
If you said new int[4][2] there would be 2 items in each row with the default value of int.
If you had a language like c# you would say int[,], but this is not possible in java.

Because of this, it is also possible to put 2 items in the first row, and 3 in the next.
So an uneven length is possible.